# Secrets cannot added to private repositories

Tags: github-actions

The button to add Secrets is missing in all privat repositories. Even for repositories in which secrets are already stored. Yesterday I added secrets to a repository. It is possible for variables.

Does anyone have an idea what this could be? I also have no notice from Github.

**Secrets**
[image]

**Variables**
[image]

**UPDATE**

I have updated my Github account to Pro. Now I can add secrets to private repositories again. Unfortunately, Github says that I have exceeded a limit. I can't find anything that says that if I exceed a limit, the addition of secrets will be blocked.

Does anyone know anything about this?

Answer (score 0):

In response to your update, as mentioned in the [documentation] (https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/using-secrets-in-github-actions#limits-for-secrets) you can store up to 1,000 organization secrets, 100 repository secrets, and 100 environment secrets.

> A workflow created in a repository can access the following number of secrets:
>
> - All 100 repository secrets
> - If the repository is assigned access to
>   more than 100 organization secrets, the workflow can only use the
>   first 100 organization secrets (sorted alphabetically by secret name).
> - All 100 environment secrets.

You can check any permissions and policies by navigating to your organization, click Settings and in the "Security" section of the sidebar, select Secrets and variables, then click Actions.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I had not found it. I have a user account and no organisation. Across all repositories I have a total of 43 secrets, 31 variables and 0 environment. I wonder if GitHub shows a hint when you reach the limit. I suspect it does. I have had it before with no variables. A few minutes later, when I tried it in other repositories, it worked again.