# How to set timeout-minutes to actions/deploy-pages@v2 step in Github Actions

Tags: github-actions

Recently Github Actions became unstable - I'm using free quota - that might have to do with something. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. I'm pretty sure there is nothing wrong with my pipeline it has to be on Github side. It was working before unchanged. Only recently this seems to be happening, and people were reporting this in the past too: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/49948

Genrally sometimes (50/50 I would say) actions/deploy-pages@v2 can't deploy and I can only see in logs:

```
Created deployment for d1ff8fb8022c89de5e06f9934cd5ac8af23f0f18, ID: d1ff8fb8022c89de5e06f9934cd5ac8af23f0f18
Getting Pages deployment status...
Current status: syncing_files
Getting Pages deployment status...
Current status: syncing_files
Getting Pages deployment status...
Current status: syncing_files
Getting Pages deployment status...
Current status: syncing_files
Getting Pages deployment status...
Current status: syncing_files
Getting Pages deployment status...
Current status: syncing_files
Getting Pages deployment status...
Current status: syncing_files
Getting Pages deployment status...
Current status: syncing_files
Getting Pages deployment status...
Current status: syncing_files

... and so on ... for 10 minutes
```

and it times out after 10 minutes

the entire pipeline is set to timeout after 10 minutes with global

```
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04 
    timeout-minutes: 10
```

but it needs to stay as is.

I would like to just limit the time for last step to 1 minute

```
  github-pages:
    environment:
      name: github-pages
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    needs: test
    steps:
      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        id: deployment
        uses: actions/deploy-pages@v2
        timeout-minutes: 1
```

but I have just noticed that it is still timeouting after 10 minutes.

It should work as I have done according to documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepstimeout-minutes

what's wrong then?

I know for sure that actions/deploy-pages@v2 should finish in my case under 10 seconds - when it normally works - so why wait 10 minutes?

Comment: If it worked otherwise, I would continue to observe it. In my case, jobs have also taken a long time in recent times. Or it even took a while for the jobs to start. See my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77089214/secrets-cannot-added-to-private-repositories). I think it was a fault with GitHub.